# Transpose rows into columns in a result SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
User    Week    OT      DW
----------------------------
A       1       28.0    54
A       2       19.5    46
A       3       10.0    38
A       4       11.0    32
B       1       25.0    54
B       2       17.5    46
B       3       10.0    40
B       4       12.0    40
```

I want to have the following result:

```
User    Week1_OT    Week2_OT    Week3_OT    Week4_OT    Week1_DW    Week2_DW    Week3_DW    Week4_DW
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A       28.0        19.5        10.0        11.0        54          46          38          32
B       25.0        17.5        10.0        12.0        54          46          40          40
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: PIVOT or CASE statements....

Comment: @MitchWheat best performance, because the data quite large.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate by user and use pivoting logic to generate the week columns:

```sql
SELECT
    User,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 1 THEN OT END) AS Week1_OT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 2 THEN OT END) AS Week2_OT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 3 THEN OT END) AS Week3_OT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 4 THEN OT END) AS Week4_OT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 1 THEN DW END) AS Week1_DW,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 2 THEN DW END) AS Week2_DW,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 3 THEN DW END) AS Week3_DW,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 4 THEN DW END) AS Week4_DW
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    User;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Temp table(_Userid CHAR(10),Week1_OT DECIMAL(12,2),Week2_OT DECIMAL(12,2),Week3_OT DECIMAL(12,2),Week4_OT DECIMAL(12,2));
DECLARE @Temp1 table(_Userid CHAR(10),Week1_Dw DECIMAL(12,2),Week2_Dw DECIMAL(12,2),Week3_Dw DECIMAL(12,2),Week4_Dw DECIMAL(12,2));

Insert into @Temp(_Userid,Week1_OT,Week2_OT,Week3_OT,Week4_OT)
select *
from 
(
  select UserId,Weekdy,OT
  from #temp
) src
pivot
(
  sum(OT)
  for weekdy in ([1], [2], [3],[4])
) piv
;


Insert into @Temp1(_Userid,Week1_DW,Week2_DW,Week3_DW,Week4_DW)
select *
from 
(
  select UserId,Weekdy,DW
  from #temp
) src
pivot
(
  sum(DW)
  for weekdy in ([1], [2], [3],[4])
) piv
;

select * from @Temp t1 Join @Temp1 t2 on t1._Userid = t2._Userid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
;with cte
as(
select * from (select week,OT from yourtable where User='A') as t  
pivot (max(OT) for week in (1,2,3,4,)) as p)
,cte2 as
(select * from (select week,OT from yourtable where User='B') as t  
pivot (max(OT) for week in (1,2,3,4,)) as p)

select * from cte
union all
select * from cte2
```